# subset xts up to but NOT including subset date OR in POSIXct

Tags: r, time-series, xts, posixct

Some example data.....

```
library(xts)

ref <- data.frame(Date = c("2/1/2000"))

frame <- read.table(text = " x   Date      Time
                             a   1/1/2000  5:00
                             a   1/1/2000  18:00 
                             a   2/1/2000  7:00",
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                         header = TRUE
                     )

ref$Date <- as.POSIXct(ref$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")   

frame$datetime <- paste(frame $Date,frame $Time, sep = " ")
frame$datetime <- as.POSIXct(frame $datetime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
frame <- xts(frame[, 1], order.by= frame [, 4] )
```

I can get all the days in frame that match ref using..

```
> frame[ paste0(":", ref$Date) ]
                    [,1]
2000-01-02 07:00:00 "a" ]
```

and all the days before and including using

```
> frame[ paste0("::", ref$Date) ]
                    [,1]
2000-01-01 05:00:00 "a" 
2000-01-01 18:00:00 "a" 
2000-01-02 07:00:00 "a"
```

but if I just want the days before I cannot do:

```
> frame[ !(paste0(ref$Date, "::")) ]
Error in !(paste0(ref$Date, "::")) : invalid argument type
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is there a simple way to do this?
2. How could this be done just using POSIXct without resorting to `xts`?

Answer (score 0):

the bets solution i have is:

```
frame[ paste0("::", ref$Date - 24*60*60) ]
```

Comment: You can use `head` with a negative `n`: `head(frame[paste0("/",ref$Date)], -1)`

Comment: Thanks GSee but I may generally have many matches for the same day and I won't necessarily know what to set `n` for the negative head. although i guess i could get this from `nrow(frame[ paste0(":", ref$Date) ])`